# Проблемы с MEXC api

Tags: python, парсер, api

Здраствуйте, столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо с биржи MEXC через API запрашивать все валютные пары, цены на них и какие сети для какой пары доступны на вывод и ввод. С первыми двумя справился быстро, а вот с последним есть непонимания. Нашёл в документации запрос, который использовал в коде ниже, но оказалось что это другое (для этого запроса необходимы ключи от биржи, и он результатом выдаёт именно какие сети на какие пары выданы разрешения). А нужно получать именно доступны ли сейчас на бирже ввод и вывод в конкретной сети конкретной монеты.

```
transfer_accesses_response = requests.get(APIURL + "/api/v3/capital/config/getall", headers={
            "X-MEXC-APIKEY" : "*********"
        })
        if transfer_accesses_response.status_code == 200:
            capitals = json.loads(transfer_accesses_response.text)
            for capital in capitals:
                networks = {}
                for network in capital["networkList"]:
                    networks[network["network"]] = {
                        "withdrawal" : network["withdrawEnable"],
                        "deposit" : network["depositEnable"]
                    }
                self.transfer_accesses[capital["coin"]] = networks
```

Comment: тоже не получается с этого эндпоинта данные забрать, ошибка 400 приходит - неверные запрос. Там надо еще подпись добавлять? или достаточно только апи ключа в хедере?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй, не совсем понял ваш вопрос. Могу предположить, что ты уже выполнил задачу по нахождению статуса депозита и вывода. но вот мое решение: `

```
        for item in data:
            for network in item.get("networkList", []):
                if network.get("coin") == coin:
                    network_name = network.get("network")
                    match = re.search(r'\((.*?)\)', network_name)
                    network_info = match.group(1) if match else network_name

                    coin_info = {
                        "withdrawStatus": network.get("withdrawEnable"),
                        "depositStatus": network.get("depositEnable"),
                        "withdrawFee": network.get("withdrawFee")

                    }
                    coin_info_dict[network_info] = coin_info

        return coin_info_dict if coin_info_dict else None`
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос